# How to save raw bytes returned by onBufferReceived() of SpeechRecognizer to encoded AMR_NB file?

Tags: android, audio, speech

I came across [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925657/capturing-audio-sent-to-googles-speech-recognition-server/5946289#5946289) on how to capture audio data returned by SpeechRecognizer. However the bytes returned are raw and I am wondering whether there is a way to encode those bytes to a AMR_NB file so that the MediaPlayer can play. Please shed some lights. Thank you so much.