# How to write down the speech recognition results while speaking?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I'm using the traditional speech recognition using Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH); All is working great, no problem.

However, now, I would like to write down in my app the speech recognition results while the user is still speaking, in the same way that voice typing do that. How can I do?

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at [this][1]. it might help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913773/speech-to-text-on-android

Comment: Thank you for the link. I tried what the guys said, the voice recognition is working well without displaying the popup, that is great, perhaps it isn't writting down the results during the diction. onPartialResults doesn't seem to work. Any idea?