# Using the native Speech-To-Text functionality within an application?

Tags: android

I'm not sure if this is possible within Android or not, but I was hoping that I could get help in finding resources to start on this. We are building an app that is, in a simplified sense, a voice journaling application. We would like to use the built in STT functionality within Android phones rather than having to move the voice recording around for processing so that we can do text analysis and present results for the user. Is this sort of functionality possible?

Comment: yes it is yes it is

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything searches of documentation, so I don't know what I'm looking for. Could you point me in a general direction I should look then?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913773/speech-to-text-on-android