# Process speech in Android browser, JavaScript API?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-browser

Is there an in browser JavaScript API that will process speech in Android Browsers? [Web Speech API](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API) doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the vocabulary is restricted to a few words, you can install pocketsphinx or [ATT toolkits](http://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=12500061&_requestid=11940) and invoke it in javascript.

A far simpler (and realistic) way is to use cloud based speech recognition.  Most android speech recognition tasks, such as google map or speech input, are done on remote servers in the cloud, as the actual speech recognition task is far too CPU/memory/battery intensive to do it on Android. There are several hosted speech recognition services in the cloud you can use. See this answer here: [Server-side Voice Recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113864/server-side-voice-recognition) .

Your task is essentially reduced to write some javascript code to record the audio, post the audio file to a server and receive the text back.