# Speech recognition from recorded file

Tags: ios, speech-recognition

I've been researching several iOS speech recognition frameworks and have found it hard to accomplish something I would think is pretty straightforward.

I have an app that allows people to record their voices. After a recording is made, they have the option to create a text version.

Looking into the services out there (i.e., Nuance) most require you to use the microphone. OpenEars allows you to do this, but the dictionary is so limited because it is an offline solution (they recommend 300 or less words).

There are a few other things going on with the app that would make it very unappealing to switch from the current recording method. For what it is worth, I am using the Amazing Audio Engine framework.

Anyone have any other suggestions for frameworks. Or is there a way to dig deeper with Nuance to transcribe a recorded file?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

For services, there are a few cloud based hosted speech recognition services you can use. You simply post the audio file to their URL and receive back the text. Most of them don't have any constraint on the vocabulary. You can of course choose any recording method you like.

See here: [Server-side Voice Recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113864/server-side-voice-recognition) . Many of them offer free trial as well.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I got this working pretty well with two recordings going on at the same time. If I notice issues, I will look into the server side option.